# Passing on the infection

Tags: bloody-good-time

I bought [Bloody Good Time](http://www.ubi.com/UK/Games/Info.aspx?pId=9098) over the weekend, and unusually, I had a few goes of the SP (i.e bots) game before having a crack at the MP game.

In certain rounds, some players are infected with a virus, and they have to pass it on to a healthy player (and flee). As you are infected, you drain away your stars (score).

There was no problem in the SP game,  but when I graduated to playing on the internets, I found it can be difficult to pass on the infection to other players. In SP, a quick bump is sufficient, but it's a real pain in MP, multiple hits are usually required. Even when I do successfully pass on the infection, I'm not expecting it to, therefore I often hang around for a split second longer and get the infection back.

3 or 4 games on different servers, and results have been equally patchy - it's killing my scores!

FYI: I have a respectable ADSL connection, and a relatively high-end PC, so I don't think it is a technical issue.

Is there particular technique that I could use to increase the chances of passing on the infection? Does anyone else experience similar issues?

Comment: I wonder if this is a hitbox vs model issue? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/what-is-a-hit-box

Comment: Your body has to touch theirs AFAIK - I know that the hitbox doesn't always match the model (headshots on BF2, anyone?) but we are talking of entire body to entire body. :)

Answer (score 1):

I decided to jump to the very edge of unanswered questions just to disappoint.  From my personal experience, the body to body "infection" hit boxes are very messy.  I feel as though sometimes you can tap someone and they will take/give the infection and other times you have to be much more "romantic" in order to transfer it.  I don't believe there is any sort of technique or tactic you can use in this instance, it is a game of luck that doesn't usually go very well.  And as far as I know they never updated/fixed that issue.

I hope this helps without being too disappointing 6ish years later.